# Encountering "Not Found" Error Only in Production Environment

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment, server, production

Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
[image]

[image]

I think the issue is in my setting.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url 

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', default='your secret key')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = 'RENDER' not in os.environ

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get('RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME')
if RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'coreapi',
    'tareas',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'calendar_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'calendar_app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(

        default='postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres',
        conn_max_age=600)
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
if not DEBUG:
    # Tell Django to copy statics to the `staticfiles` directory
    # in your application directory on Render.
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

    # Turn on WhiteNoise storage backend that takes care of compressing static files
    # and creating unique names for each version so they can safely be cached forever.
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# cors auth
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:5173']

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

my app.jsx is:

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { TaskPage } from "./pages/TaskPage";
import { TaskFormPage } from "./pages/TaskFormPage";
import { Navigation } from "./components/Navigations";
import { TaskEditPage } from "./pages/TaskEditPage";
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navigation></Navigation>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/tasks" />} />
        <Route path="/tasks" element={<TaskPage />} />
        <Route path="/tasks-create" element={<TaskFormPage />} />
        <Route path="/tasks-edit" element={<TaskEditPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

thanks for the help in advance. I have been with this error for 2 days I don't know what to do

I'm facing a puzzling issue with my web application where I receive a "Not Found: The requested resource was not found on this server" error, but only in the production environment. The application works fine in my development environment. I've checked the URL but I'm still unable to pinpoint the issue